# @InjectMocks annotation. java code analog

Tags: java, testing, spring-mvc, junit, mockito

I want on one method use mock eventService and in another real eventService.

```
   @Mock(name = "eventService")
        private EventService eventService;

        @InjectMocks
        private CandidateMenuController candidateMenuController = new CandidateMenuController();
```

How to write analog this code inside method.
I have `CandidateMenuController candidateMenuController` as class field. But at one method I want  to use specific eventService realization.

**P.S** I have **not** constructor and set get method for `EventService`

Comment: Could you just make two different `CandidateMenuController` objects, one with `@InjectMocks` and one without; then use whichever object is appropriate for each test?

Comment: Actually CandidateMenuController contain many different objects and its use.

Comment: So is there a setter for the one field that you want to be able to control the value of?

Comment: no, but @InjectMocks works and without it

Comment: You may have to either write such a setter, or use reflection.  You can't tell `@InjectMocks` to be selective about which fields to inject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you do not have any `setter` method to set the value of `EventService`, you can use reflection to set the value for `EventService`:

```
@Test
public void testWithRealization() {
Field field = candidateMenuController.getClass().getDeclaredField("eventService");
field.set(candidateMenuController, new EventServiceImpl());

// Test Code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `@MockitoJunitRunner` from class and in method where you want to use mock do `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);`
In  method where you want use specific implementation of `EventService` you have to create it manually by invoking constructor.

Comment: I have not understood How I pass my mock to CandidateMenuController instance?

Comment: Havent seen that you dont have setter available. I'm confused. Why you want to use specific `EventService` ? If you testing `CandidateMenuController` test it, and test implementations of `EventService's` in another test classes.

Comment: Maybe it is bad style? but I want to test it. initMocks inject mock, that annotated by @Mock But my mock creates inside method

Comment: It's not bad style.  Sometimes it's the simplest way to avoid null pointer exceptions all the way through your tests.

Comment: Anyway you need either constuctor parameter or setter.. theres still reflection. Consider refactoring your code or create different test cases. Remember that testability of code is very important!